# AppleScript get variable from a specific column in a TSV file

Tags: csv, applescript

I am new when it comes to using AppleScript, and I need you help with the following:

I have a TSV file formatted like this:

```
       [COLUMN A] [COLUMN B] [COLUMN C] [COLUMN D] (...)
[Line 1]Data      Data       Data       Data
[Line 2]Data      Data       Data       Data
(...)
```

I would like, for each line of the file, to perform a new Google Image search. The keywords would be taken from let's say column A and D, but not from column B or C.

I managed to create a script that opens the file, and performs the search, so my problem is "only" to be able to use some specific columns, not all of them (which is what I am doing with my current script).

Here is my script:

```
set thetext to read (choose file) 
repeat with line_number from 1 to count of paragraphs in thetext 
    set line_text to paragraph line_number of thetext 

    tell application "Google Chrome" 
        activate
        tell front window to make new tab at after (get active tab) with properties {URL:"http://images.google.com/images?ie=ISO-8859-1&hl=en&btnG=Google+Search&q=" & line_text}
    end tell
end repeat
```

How would you do to "split the line" (line_text in the script) and use only specific columns for the search ? It is a TSV file so it uses tabulations between the columns of data.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `text item delimiters` are for. Your `line_text` is a string in the form `"Data1\tData2\tData3\tData4"`, so let's use that as an example:

```
set line_text to "Data1\tData2\tData3\tData4"
set the text item delimiters to "\t"
set theData to every text item of line_text
```

Result:

```
{"Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4"}
```

Now if you want the fourth column data for that line you just ask for `item 4 of theData`.